# Disable Form Buttons for Specific Time in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms, formbuilder

I want to Disable five Buttons(Student,Parent,Guardian,Employee,Salary) from MENU Form for during non-business hours i-e 8am-1pm(8-13)
I code this in FormBuilder > DatabaseObjects > MyDB(i-e School) >Tables >MENU>Triggers
When i Save it it show error
**ERROR:**
**PDE-UTG007 Trigger contains an error**
**PLS-00201:identifier'ENABLED'must be declared**

```
BEGIN
IF (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DY') IN ('SAT','SUN')) OR (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24:MI') NOT BETWEEN '08:00' AND '13:00') 
THEN
set_item_property('control.Student', enabled, property_false); 
set_item_property('control.Parent', enabled, property_false); 
set_item_property('control.Guardian', enabled, property_false); 
set_item_property('control.Employee', enabled, property_false); 
set_item_property('control.Salary', enabled, property_false); 
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20500, 'You can access Database only during normal business hours.');
END IF;
end;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP14B.png)

Answer (score 3):

This code should be created in Forms' Triggers internally, not in a Database Trigger with converting `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` to `MESSAGE('You can...'); MESSAGE()`. You can embed the code within a Procedure of Forms such as

```
PROCEDURE Disable_Buttons IS
BEGIN
  IF (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') IN ('SAT', 'SUN')) OR
     (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI') NOT BETWEEN '08:00' AND '13:00') THEN
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('control.Student', enabled, property_false);
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('control.Parent', enabled, property_false);
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('control.Guardian', enabled, property_false);
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('control.Employee', enabled, property_false);
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('control.Salary', enabled, property_false);
    MESSAGE('You can access Database only during normal business hours.');
    MESSAGE('');
  END IF;
END;
```

and call `Disable_Buttons` from `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger, along with `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` triggers of those five buttons as at the top of the existing codes in order to prevent the execution of the rest of the code for already running sessions of applications during those periods.

Or as being more straightforward, you can add the `Disable_Buttons` into `WHEN-NEW-BLOCK-INSTANCE` trigger of `control` block instead of individually adding into the `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` triggers of those five buttons.